# MongoDB multi-field $lookup performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could someone please explain the 40x performance difference in these two $lookup aggregation pipelines?  Using Mongo 4.4.2.

```
[
    {'$match': {}},
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'players',
            'localField': 'player_id',
            'foreignField': 'id',
            'as': 'result',
        }
    },
]
```

The above pipeline requires about 3 seconds in a collection of 5000 documents, matching against a 'players' collection of 2600 documents.  The 'players' collection has a unique index on 'id'.  The following query, using a trivial multi-field match, requires about 120 seconds on the same data:

```
[
    {'$match': {}},
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'players',
            'let': {
                'pid': '$player_id'
            },
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match': { '$expr': { '$and': [
                        { '$eq': ['$id', '$$pid']},
                    ]}}
                }
            ],
            'as': 'result',
        }
    },
]
```

Am I doing something wrong in specifying the $match requirements so that it can't use the index on 'id'?

Comment: refer the JIRA ticket [SERVER-31760](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31760) and comments

Comment: Where is the multi-field match? I see only one field.

Comment: I reduced my query to one indexed field for the example, the issue is the same for one or multiple fields in the match.

Comment: @turivishal that ticket does seem to describe the issue, but says it was fixed in one of the 3.6 releases.  There is another ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36818 that describes a similar problem with multi-key indexes, but in my example the 'players' collection has a single index on the 'id' key.

Comment: @Rakurai check your parent collection indexes, there should be single index on `player_id`.